# Sort by RefinableInt using SharePoint Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I've this code below:

```
https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Negocio/OfertaParticulares/_api/web/folders('Dinamico')/folders('55')/folders('Contas%20%C3%A0%20Ordem')/folders?$select=ID,Title,Created,Name,ListItemAllFields&$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

I also have a field with a RefinableInt05 associated.
How can I sort by using my RefinableInt?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a search resultat source containing the query and set the RefinableInt as the sort by field in the query builder. That would also ensure that you don't have to change the code just because the query changes